# Drop event not firing on wpf grid

Tags: c#, grid, uwp

I'm trying to develop an ancient form of chess, Chaturaji, as an assignment for school. I've got some very basic xaml setup that should allow me to drag and drop an image element within a grid.

```
<Page
    x:Class="Projectg.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Projectg"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid  AllowDrop="True" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition>
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="900">
            </ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition>
            </ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="900"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="Transparent" x:Name="grdGrid" AllowDrop="True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Drop="grdGrid_Drop" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />

            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image CanDrag="True"  x:Name="Image" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="/images/boat.png" DragStarting="Boat_DragStarting" Drop="Boat_Drop" DragOver="Image_DragOver"  ></Image>
            <Image CanDrag="True" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="/images/horse.png" ></Image>
            <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="/images/elephant.png" ></Image>
            <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="/images/crown.png" ></Image>

            <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="/images/pawn.png" ></Image>
            <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="/images/pawn.png" ></Image>
            <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Source="/images/pawn.png" ></Image>
            <Image Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="80" Width="80" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Source="/images/pawn.png" ></Image>


        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

When I try to drag the image over the grid the mouse shows the “Drop Not Allowed” cursor and  releasing the image does not fire the Drop event. I asked a teacher about this and she said it was probably because I did not set a background for my grid.

I quickly updated the code, but no luck, the event still did not fire. She didn't really know what was going on and told me to email her if the problem persisted.

I thought I would ask here first.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Try handling DragOver and/or DragEnter and setting `e.Effects` in the handler(s).

Comment: Hi, the DragOver event does fire. If that's what you're asking?

Comment: Try `IsHitTestVisible="True"` on the `Grid` also. Otherwise it's not getting mouse messages. I forgot that.

Comment: IsHitTestVisible="True" was added but I'm still only getting a fire on the DragOver event and not the Drop event. I aslo tried adding a drop event to the image that is being dragged, but that also did not fire.

Comment: Are you setting `e.Effects` in the `DragOver` handler to something meaningful? `DragDropEffects.Move`, `DragDropEffects.Copy`, whatever. The Drop event on an element is raised when you drop ON the element, not when you drop the element on something else.

Comment: This works for me: `<Grid IsHitTestVisible="True" AllowDrop="True" DragOver="Grid_DragOver" Drop="Grid_Drop">...` c# `private void Grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Effects = DragDropEffects.All;
        }

        private void Grid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Dropped");
        }`

Comment: I'm sorry I apparently mislabeled the question. I'm working on a UWP app and not a WPF app. The e.Effects does not exist within my project.

Comment: [`e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/drag-and-drop?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much, sorry for the miscommunication!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick glance at the [MSDN UWP **Drag and Drop** page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-to-app/drag-and-drop?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) suggests that you need to handle the `DragOver` event, and indicate what drop operations the control will accept (true in any form of XAML and IIRC winforms etc. as well). In UWP, that's the `AccepttedOperation` property on the event args object (WPF calls that property `Effects` and it's a different enum type):

```
private void Grid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
}
```